# Attribute img not allowed on element img at this point.Error

Tags: html, css

When you click the image in my html page, it opens that image's web page.

I also named the images by class so I can adjust each image's specs in a separate CSS sheet.

Here is my code:

```
*/

<img class = "paypal" img src= "images/paypal.jpg" alt= "Logo for PayPal"> </a>

/*
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

"Error: Attribute img not allowed on element img at this point."

How can I maintain my goal of referencing each image separately while following syntax?

Comment: You seem to have missed the code, could you please include it. Also can you tell us were you are seeing the error?

Comment: It sounds like your code is malformed. An `<img>` tag should not have an `img` attribute. Perhaps you didn't close one of your `<img>` tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have an extra/erroneous "IMG" inside the image html element which is getting read as an attribute and causing the problerm

replace :

```
<img class = "paypal" img src= "images/paypal.jpg" alt= "Logo for PayPal">
```

with:

```
<img class = "paypal" src= "images/paypal.jpg" alt= "Logo for PayPal">
```

Comment: I fixed it but in a different way.

Here's what I did:
<i img src= "images/paypal.jpg" class= "paypal" alt= "Logo for PayPal">

Comment: Why use the I tag with an image attribute instead of just using the img tag though?